# Convert Ada type definitions in spec files to ASN.1 schema

Tags: ada, auto-generate, asn.1

I was wondering if anyone has ever gone from Ada source->ASN.1 Schema. Ideally I want to suck up all the type definitions in my spec files to create a library of data types in ASN format that could later by run through an ASN.1 compiler for other languages. I also want to use this to auto generate the serialize/deserialize functions for my existing record definitions.

The goal is to create a "dumb" test driver that could be fed commands from an external application, that includes the test inputs, and spits back the outputs.

The effort by hand would be massive (~2-3k type/subtype declarations).

Comment: Just an idea: Have you considered using an ASIS based program that assists at creating things for the "dumb" test driver, maybe outputs definitions that these can use?

Comment: We use GNAT2XML to convert Ada source code to XML, and then do extensive type analysis, including building data layout files and XML schemas. I mention this because we avoided having to work with ASIS, instead doing DOM traversal and manipulation. Still a lot of work, but XML experience was much easier to come by.

Comment: _gnat2xml_ is an ASIS application under the hood, it’s just that the users don’t need to know that!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I've read something about an ESA funded Open Source Ada ASN.1 compiler.  It may do the job.

If that's not quite doing your job, you are welcome to grab the sources for my [command-line driver generator](https://bitbucket.org/sparre/command-line-parser-generator) and reuse the ASIS based Ada package specification parser from it to generate types in ASN format.

Comment: It's buried deep inside the ESA's Taste Framework: http://taste.tuxfamily.org/. Though given what the TASTE framework does, I'd be faintly surprised if it does what the OP wants (it's definitely all about defining ASN.1 schema).

Comment: It's pretty cool what they've built into TASTE. Take a look at their presentation: http://download.tuxfamily.org/taste/misc/presentation.pdf